# How to attach an external library's javadocs built with javadoc 1.7 to Android projects under Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, javadoc

In the past I have managed to attach the javadocs for third party libraries to Android projects under Eclipse, using the fairly convoluted method of adding lines to the **libraryname.jar.properties** file in the **libs** directory. I know how to do this, both for jar files alone and with all files expanded from the jar. Thus I can have the 'hover over help' working.

I find that with some later libraries' javadocs built with ***version 1.7***,e.g osmdroid-android-4.0.jar where the expanded html contains:

```
<!-- Generated by javadoc (version 1.7.0_05) on Sun Oct 20 20:05:35 CEST 2013 -->
```

when I reference the javadoc location in the same manner as has previuosly worked, then the help on hover does not work and the logcat produces:

> Runtime error while computing text hover

I have found some fairly old references to Eclipse not supporting 1.7 javadocs, e.g [Old reference here](https://forums.bukkit.org/threads/solved-eclipse-runtime-error-while-computing-text-hover.71806/)

I've found  that if the sources are available, then I can get the hover help by including a reference to the source, e.g.

```
#doc=c:\\dev\\docs\\osmdroid-android-4.0-javadoc
src=c:\\dev\\docs\\osmdroid-android-4.0-source\\osmdroid-android-4.0-sources.jar
```

However, for other libraries, the source may not be available, so I'm asking if anyone knows how to make the hover over help and context assist work for version 1.7 javadoc files in Eclipse Andoid projects?

I am using Eclipse Indigo and JDK6.